# jQuery - clone() images without re-downloading them

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, caching

So if you `clone()` an img element, then the browser will retrieve the images `src` the same way it did for the original element. This means that either a new HTTP request is initiated, or it fetches it from cache.

What I am trying to do is `clone()` images without having to re-load them.

One (sort-of) solution is to cache them with `Etag` and `Last-Modified`, so that the browser just initiates new HTTP connections which return with 304, and the image isn't actually downloaded. But the problem is, if the image source changes between the original page load, and when the image is cloned, then the clone image will be different from the original.

Another solution I came up with, is to set an `Expires` header of `time() + 1 year` on the images. That way every time an image is cloned, it is automatically fetched from the cache. Then, on every page load, append the current timestamp to the image `src` so that it loads a new one (skipping the cache). But the problem with that is that now images can never be cached. I would like to implement an `Etag` and `Last-Modified` cache for when the images are loaded during page load.

Is there any way to clone an image directly?

Comment: You could turn it into a data url, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript

Comment: Tried `canvas` element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas ?

Comment: It kind of bothers me that I have to specify the mime type and image quality. It would be much preferred if I could copy the image without having to know it's properties beforehand.